# I have a indian passport and have a French permanent residence card valid for 10 years. Can I go to the UK for a few days to visit without a visa?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, visa-free-entry

I have a French permanent residence card valid for 10 years.  Can I go to the UK for a few days to visit without a visa?

Answer (score 1):

If your nationality needs a visa to enter the UK, then you will need one, except if leaving for a third country (e.g. France-UK-Sweden) no later than 23:59 the next day, in which case your passport and French residence permit are enough. For this, you have to enter and exit the UK by air.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether you need a visa to enter the UK on [this UK government page](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa), which is current as of November 6, 2018.

Because you have not revealed any information about your own nationality and travel document, we cannot click through on that page to find an answer to your question.